# Index-only scan on table with all columns in PK

Tags: postgresql

For the normal index postgresql can include in the plan Heap Fetches for the index-only scan operation.

Is it the same for the table all columns of which are in PK (like intermediate table for many-to-many relationship)?

I am on Postgresql 11.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Whatever the situation/motivation of the index is, either it can support an index only scan for a given query, or it can't.

Comment: Yes, but the question is will postgresql use Heap Fetches for the index-only scan operation on the index covering entire table?